# Chinese characters in wine

Tags: wine, language

I am using Wine to use a Windows interface to WeChat in Linux. WeChat is a popular messaging program in China, similar to WhatsApp.

Many of my messages are in Chinese. Unfortunately, they are not displayed properly. I think I don't have the font. Instead of Chinese characters, I just see squares.

How can I fix it? I am using Ubuntu Mate

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDE
```

Comment: You need to install the fonts. Which distribution are you using ? CentOS ? Ubuntu ?

Comment: Does your environment have Chinese fonts installed already ? 
Check with the command `locale`

Comment: @jay thanks I added the information. I presumed I had to fix something on the wine/windows emulation side. Are you saying maybe I need to install the fonts on the linux side?

Comment: Have a look at this answer  https://askubuntu.com/questions/86335/installing-other-fonts-on-wine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a very good article about how to set up WeChat in Wine
https://ferrolho.github.io/blog/2018-12-22/wechat-desktop-on-linux

Here are the essential parts of it in case it gets unavailable

**Providing a Chinese font**

For the Chinese characters to be rendered correctly we need to provide Wine with Chinese font. We will use winetricks for this, which is a helper script to download and install extra Wine stuff.

Download winetricks:

```
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
```

Set the executable flag:

```
chmod +x winetricks
```

Some winetricks “packages” require a few external tools to be installed. We need cabextract:

```
sudo apt install cabextract
```

And now we install the fonts and some other libraries:

```
./winetricks corefonts gdiplus riched20 riched30 wenquanyi
```

Finally, we need to edit regedit to enable the font we just installed. Download this [.reg file](https://gist.github.com/swordfeng/c3fd6b6fcf6dc7d7fa8a).

Open regedit with the command:

```
./winetricks regedit
```

In the Menu bar, click Registry and select Import Registry File…

When the browser shows up, select the .reg file you have just downloaded.

**We are now ready to install WeChat itself.**

Comment: Thank you. This answer & the blog post will hopefully help many people